# Ubuntu Как сделать файл исполняемым?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Скачал run Xammp но написано что надо его сделать его исполняемым , как это делается правильно ?

Comment: man chmod. Или не вдаваясь в подробности chmod a+x filename

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заходите в свойства файла - Права - нажимаете на галочку Разрешить выполнение файла как программы

Answer (score 5):

Воспользуйтесь командой [chmod](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

```
[sudo] chmod +x <файл>
```

Comment: Только `sudo` может быть и лишним тут.

Comment: @andy, думаю вы правы, убрал.